# new object[] {} vs Array.Empty<object>()

Tags: c#, arrays

When I type the following code:

```
object[] objects = new object[] { };
```

Visual Studio tells me:

> Avoid unnecessary zero-length allocations. Use `Array.Empty<object>()`
> instead.

Are there any actual implications of using one over the other?

What is the reason for the warning?

Comment: Hm, well every call to `Array.Empty()` returns the same array, whereas your code will create multiple arrays.  It might be to avoid unnecessary overhead.

Comment: You're creating something you don't need to create. Array.Empty references a static readonly property, so there is only one instance within the appdomain.

Comment: @Will Kindly put that as an answer.

Comment: Some points mentioned for [Should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” to intitialize a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263191/205233) may also apply.

Comment: @MikeCheel take a look at this link: http://justinvp.com/2015/07/20/array-empty/

Comment: If Visual Studio can detect this and generate a warning, why can't the compiler fix it?

Comment: @Joe I'm guessing here but there maybe times when you want multiple empty arrays.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727146/how-do-i-initialize-an-empty-array-in-c

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You're creating an empty array. Which will always be empty, as you cannot change the capacity of the array instance (it just sounds weird to say you can't change its *length*, I don't know, why). Every time you do this, you create another instance of an array that can never be used. Doing this a lot may result in wasted GC and memory pressure, thus the warning.

Instead of creating empty arrays, just use `Array.Empty<T>()` as it suggests. This method returns an array using this static class

```
internal static class EmptyArray<T>
{
    public readonly static T[] Value;

    static EmptyArray()
    {
        EmptyArray<T>.Value = new T[0];
    }
}
```

Since it's `static` and `readonly`, there's only ever one instance of this empty array in the entire app domain. An empty array is essentially immutable, so caching the instance isn't a problem. And it allows you to forego special-casing empty array creation in your algorithms if you find yourself eyeballing an elegant code path that is creating tons of empty arrays.

`Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is the Linq to Objects equivalent and is also useful for not wasting allocations for empty stuff.

Comment: this is interesting! i didnt realize that the class is `static` and `readonly` and it will only create one instance of the empty array...made me think about the disaster under the hood in the huge application my team has been working on. its a shame that visual studio does not provide a reason for its fix...!

Answer (score 9):

Using Array.Empty is useful to avoid unnecessary memory allocation.
Refer the code from .NET Library itself below:

```
[Pure]
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public static T[] Empty<T>()
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<T[]>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<T[]>().Length == 0);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    return EmptyArray<T>.Value;
}
...
// Useful in number of places that return an empty byte array to avoid unnecessary memory allocation.
internal static class EmptyArray<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] Value = new T[0];
}
```

Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,bc9fd1be0e4f4e70

Comment: I want to add a comment on Code Contracts, as they are not supported in .NET 5+ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts)